# FactoryPattern with Generics in Java

Tags: java, refactoring

i'm new to java and im trying to use the Factory Pattern.

My App simply imports Data from an Excelsheet into an ArrayList by a given Pojo/Bean.
As i have more than one Bean i decided to create a Config object and use a factory pattern.
The cfg object configures the generic extractor and the factory method returns the concrete Extractor. In this case the MyDataExtracor.
The importExcel method simply runs through every line in the excel and adds the extracted data as object per line to a list.

But the line `List<MyData> myDataList = e.importExcel();`
throws the following error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#1-of ?> to List<MyData>`

anyone has a hint what im doing wrong?

Heres my code:
**main**

```
ExtractorConfig ec = new ExtractorConfig();
ec.setType(MyData.class);
ec.setFileName("MyData.xlsx");
ec.setStartRow(2d);
ec.setEndRow(3241d);
ec.setSheetName("Sheet1");

Extractor e = Extractor.createFromConfig(ec);
List<MyData> myDataList = e.importExcel();
```

**Extractor.java**

```
public abstract class Extractor {
    
    public abstract List<?> importExcel();

    public abstract ExtractorBean processRow(Row currentRow);

    public static Extractor createFromConfig(ExtractorConfig ec) {
        if (ec.getC() == MyData.class)
            return new MyDataExtractor(ec);

        return null;

    }
}
```

**MyDataExtractor.java**
public class MyDataExtractor extends Extractor {

```
    ExtractorConfig c;

    public MyDataExtractor(ExtractorConfig c) {
        super();
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyData> importExcel() {

        List<MyData> aList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
        // some code
        // loop through worksheet
        MyData aMyDataObject = processRow(currentRow);
        aList.add(aMyDataObject);
        // end of loop

        return aList;
    }



    public MyData processRow(Row currentRow) {

        MyData myDataObject = new MyData();
        // do some stuff like setting data
        return myDataObject;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Extractor` like you want to itneeds to have a generic type of its own, e.g. `Extractor<T>` and then `public abstract List<T> importExcel()`. Then define the concrete implementation as `MyDataExtractor implements Extractor<MyData>`.

Additionally, you need to adjust the config and factory method, e.g. like this:

```
public class ExtractorConfig<T> {
  public Extractor<T>(Class<T> type) { ... }

  Class<T> getType();
}

//need to suppress the warning about the cast
//using E here in order to avoid confusion with <T> of Extractor<T>
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E> static Extractor<E> createFromConfig(ExtractorConfig<E> ec) {
    //this isn't that elegant though as Extractor would now need to know all implementations and their data classes
    if (MyData.class.equals(ec.getType()))
        //unfortunately this cast is necessary
        return (Extractor<E>)new MyDataExtractor(ec);

    return null;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ExtractorConfig<MyData> ec = new ExtractorConfig(MyData.class);
...

Extractor<MyData> e = Extractor.createFromConfig(ec);
List<MyData> myDataList = e.importExcel();
```

Note that if you want to be more flexible with possible implementations, you might need to use a kind of registry (factory factory) with either contains singleton extractors, prototypes or metafactories.

Simple example using meta factories:

```
interface ExtractorFactory<T> {
  Class<T> getType();

  Extractor<T> buildExtractor(ExtractorConfig<T> ec);
}

class ExtractorRegistry {
   Map<Class<?>, ExtractorFactory<?>> factories = ...;

   void registerFactory(ExtractorFactory<?> factory) {
      factories.put(factory.getType(), factory);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   <T> Extractor<T> build(ExtractorConfig<T> ec) {
     //same ugly but necessary cast, warning needs to be suppressed
     ExtractorFactory<T> f = (ExtractorFactory)factories.get(ec.getType());
     if( f != null ) return f.buildExtractor(ec);
    
     return null;
   }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ExtractorRegistry registry = ...//get it from somewhere (or make it static, but that's not preferred)
registry.registerFactory(new MyDataExtractorFactory());

Extractor<MyData> e = registry .build(ec);
List<MyData> myDataList = e.importExcel();
```

Finally a word on those casts:

Since you'll want to deal with different and potentially unrelated types in your factory methods (or the registry method that returns factories) you need to cast from the concrete types you get (e.g. `MyData` defined by `MyDataExtractor` to the generic or wildcard type of the method.

However, this is ok if you make sure that those casts will always succeed. The warnings are there to tell you this is potentially unsafe and thus you need to be extra careful not to break it. If you are sure this can't break, supress the warnings :)